# ProgressDialog in RecyclerView adapter issue

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-recyclerview

when i try to use progressdialog in recyclerview adapter i have exception message:

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

i know that everything with used context is ok because Glide few lines below ProgressBar use the same context. Any idea whats the problem?
My adapter class:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;

import java.util.List;



public class ShopsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    List<String> shopsList;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView thumbnail;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        }
    }

    public ShopsAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> shopsList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.shopsList = shopsList;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.shop_card,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

        shopsList.get(position);
        try{
            progressDialog.show();
            String stringformat = String.format(".../%s.png", shopsList.get(position));
            Glide.with(mContext).load(stringformat).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    //progressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            }).centerCrop().fitCenter().into(holder.thumbnail);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Dsdfs", e.getMessage());
            Glide.with(mContext).load("http://...Zabka.png").centerCrop().fitCenter().into(holder.thumbnail);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return shopsList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: add ur adapter calling code

Comment: adapter = new ShopsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), shopsNames);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

> adapter = new ShopsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), shopsNames);

TO

> adapter = new ShopsAdapter(this, shopsNames);

Comment: i can't because adapter is call inside AsyncTask class

Comment: if this doesn't work use CLASS_NAME.this   class_name is your activity name

Comment: adapter = new ShopsAdapter(classname.this, shopsNames);

Comment: yes, you have right. Could you tell me why getApplicationContext works with Glide but not with progressdialog?

Comment: ActivityName.this refers to activity context. getApplicationContext () refers to the application context.

Comment: progress dialog cannot use it because It's not a complete Context, supporting everything that Activity does. Various things you will try to do with this Context will fail, mostly related to the GUI.  where as Glide is not based on UI taskes

Comment: Thanks again, you are best:)